# HTTPS file transfer stopping when it encounters 0x1a (substitute character)

Tags: https, server, openssl

I'm trying to send binary files using an openSSL server, but the transfer stops just before it should be sending a 0x1A character.

I was able to send 8MB+ text files, but with both binaries I tried sending, it stopped after 20kB, right before the 0x1A character, so the size of the file is not a problem. I'm on Windows 10 and using openSSL to run the server.

```
winpty openssl s_server -WWW -key key.pem -cert cert.pem -port 8075
```

Using the following command, I am able to download text files without any issue, but it "fails" before the whole binary file was sent.

```
winpty curl -v -k https://192.168.1.100:8075/hello-world.bin --output hello-world-recv.bin
```

The verbose from the curl command is as follows (removed the first part where it's about the certificates and handshake):

```
GET /hello-world.bin HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.1.100:8075
> User-Agent: curl/7.60.0
> Accept: */*
>
{ [5 bytes data]
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 ok
< Content-type: text/plain
<
{ [16339 bytes data]
100 19270    0 19270    0     0  43995      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 45663
* Closing connection 0
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, Client hello (1):
} [2 bytes data]
```

As we can see, only 19kB of data was sent, but the original file is 1.2MB.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check in OpenSSL-source function `www_body` in `apps/s_server.c` (line 3254 in 1.1.1b): it opens the file in default `"r"` mode, which might be *text mode* in Windows, that means `CRLF` will be converted to `LF` and `SUB` will be interpreted as end of file.